# Eclipse: Could not initialize class com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient

Tags: eclipse, spotify

Why *eclipse-SDK-4.7M4-win32-x86_64* is showing

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details. Could not
>   initialize class com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient

...if I have no spotify plugin or any spotify client installed on my PC?

*(maybe I had spotify desktop for windows, long time ago, but nothing for Eclipse)*

--update

the log file have some errors, but nothing related to Spotify:

[image]

Comment: What does the error log show? (.log file in the workspace .metadata directory)

Comment: @greg-449 updated

Comment: Well the log looks like you are trying to use a workspace which has been used by an Eclipse which had EGit, M2E and JBoss installed. The Eclipse SDK download is very minimal and doesn't contain a lot of the plugins that the configuration of the workspace wants to use. Try a new, empty, workspace.